# lattice symmetries portrayed in animation

Tags: group-theory, integer-lattices

Below is an animated gif by [Dave Whyte](http://beesandbombs.tumblr.com/):
[image]

- What is the orbifold/fibrifold notation for the symmetries of the lattice depicted below? (a la /The Symmetries of Things/?
- Are there related theta function identities corresponding to those symmetries?